# MySQLdb Python - does my code look correct?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python

```
c.execute("""DELETE FROM data
WHERE user = %s AND machine = %s""" , (user, machine))
```

I have two variables that were sent with get (technically they were machine+user, and then I split the variable based on the plus), who were then respectively assigned to the variables machine and user.

Theoretically this script should work, correct? What am I doing incorrectly? It does not delete the record I wish it would, or any at all.

Comment: That part of it looks fine - have you checked that `user` and `machine` are what you expect, and are the same as in the database?

Comment: Have you called `connection.commit()` to commit the transaction? (Needed for INNODB tables, though not MyISAM tables).

Comment: While you're at it, a) verify that c is what it should be and b) test it with a fully hard-coded query string c) check the error returned from c.execute

Comment: To debug this, you might also want to print out `c._executed`, which will show you the string that was sent to the MySQL server. Then test that string at the `mysql>` command-line prompt. Does it work as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [my data won't go away](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#my-data-disappeared-or-won-t-go-away). Hint: `commit()` needed